# waypoints: JSONRepresentation failed. Error trace is: (null)

Tags: ios, json, google-maps

iphone project with google map api:

Im trying to implement waypoints to gain more detalied and custom routes with "via" points or waypoints. BUT the "JSON representation" is giving me grey hair...

I tried quite a few of the suggestions via google search, but nothing seams to work and there a no one with exactly the same kind of issue. It returns null no matter what ?
My thought is that google changed something in there api but I just cant find the error and whats causing it...

I really hope someone knows how to fix this.

Im using kishikawakatsumis as reference MapKit-Route-Directions.
https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/MapKit-Route-Directions

The call is like this:

```
 if ([wayPoints count] > 0) {
NSArray *routePoints = [NSArray arrayWithObject:mFirstCity.mCityName];
routePoints = [routePoints arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:wayPoints];
routePoints = [routePoints arrayByAddingObject:destination];
[mDirections loadFromWaypoints:routePoints options:options];
} else {
[mDirections loadWithStartPoint:mFirstCity.mCityName endPoint:destination options:options];
}
```

Kind regards
Jakob

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured out a solution. 
If you have the same situation as me, you can replace the loadFromWayPoints methos with this method and and another:

```
- (void)loadFromWaypoints:(NSArray *)waypoints options:(UICGDirectionsOptions *)options {

NSString* msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"loadFromWaypoints(%@, %@)", [waypoints JSONRepresentation], [options JSONRepresentation]];
mstr = [msg retain];
[self performSelector:@selector(LFWP:)  withObject:msg afterDelay:1];
```

}
- (void)LFWP:(NSString *)message
{
    [googleMapsAPI stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:message];

}

I also put an (!) into the if in NSOBJECT+SBJSON.m

```
- (NSString *)JSONRepresentation {
SBJsonWriter *jsonWriter = [SBJsonWriter new];    
NSString *json = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:self];
if (!json)
    NSLog(@"-JSONRepresentation failed. Error trace is: %@", [jsonWriter errorTrace]);
[jsonWriter release];
return json;
```

}

The reason is ( my interpretation ) that the json/google call need a little dalay in order to reach data and get them back... Im not sure thats correct, but it work now.

I hope it can help someone...